# CSS. На странице применяется только цвета (background и color) hover, а active не действует (именно цвета)

Tags: css, css3, css-selectors

```
`ul.tese a:active{
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: small; 
    color: rgb(223, 120, 2); 
    background:rgba(174, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
ul.tese a:hover{
    color: rgb(28, 53, 195); 
    background:rgba(59, 255, 245, 0.623);
    border: 1px solid blueviolet;
    transform: scale(1.3) rotate(20deg);
    transition-property: background, transform;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}`
```

Comment: Скорее всего где-то задан другой цвет с более веским селектором или и !important; Откройте через просмотр кода и проверьте откуда берется цвет элементу.